# Threading with Generic Lists

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, generics

I am new to threading world, I have less(no) idea about threading. Please give me support to solve my following issue.

1. I have 2 generic lists (list1, list2)
2. I will iterate trough list1
3. Do some processing and need to store result in list2

I need to process items in list1 batch by batch in given number of threads, store all outputs in single list (list2)

**Q1**. How to make batches from list1 and give to threads ?
**Q2**. How we identify when one tread has finished its operation ?
**Q3**. How we give next item to finished tread ?
**Q4**. Will it be cause accessing issues to list2 (since it is accessed by multiple threads) ?

Comment: please show some code... what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have big code and harder(and unpractical)to show here. As I said I have NO idea how to do this with threading.  

My code only works in a Single Thread, What I need to do is make it multi-threaded

Comment: var list2 = list1.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(BatchSize).Select(x => x.SomeProcessing()).ToList()

Answer (score 3):

> Q1. How to make batches from list1 and give to threads ?

`Parallel.ForEach` would be a good start; [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001.aspx)

> Q2. How we identify when one tread has finished its operation ?

`Parallel.ForEach` will handle that; once the ForEach exits, all work is complete

> Q3. How we give next item to finished tread ?

Again, `Parallel.ForEach` handles that

> Q4. Will it be cause accessing issues to list2 (since it is accessed by multiple threads) ?

Yes; so either synchronize access (`lock` etc while adding) , or use a `ConcurrentBag<T>`

Comment: ForEach will iterate one by one, isn't it ?

I need to process multiple items from list1 at the same time, in different threads.

Comment: @Buddhi no, it won't - `Parallel.ForEach` - the hint is in the word "Parallel". See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001.aspx

Comment: Agree ... using Parallel.ForEach will solve your problems without causing you headaches :D

Comment: But I am still using .Net ver 2.00 so hope I can't use this... Isn't it ?

Comment: Or a ConcurrentQueue if he will be needs the stuff in order.

Comment: @Buddhi this is .NET 4.0 (or 3.5 with add-on dlls)

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for the classes in the

```
System.Collections.Concurrent
```

namespace.

Microsofts MSDN has listet some articles about list in a multi-threading environment: [Parallel programming series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/tags/parallel_2d00_programming/)
You might be looking for the last article of it: [Blocking Collection and the Producer-Consumer Problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/08/12/blocking-collection-and-the-producer-consumer-problem.aspx)

There is a longer and specialized article [Concurrent Collections in the .NET Framework 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/gg274329.aspx) by Bill Wagner that goes deeper into the topic.